# How can i debugging CGI file of lighttpd with gdbserver

Tags: mips, lighttpd, ida, gdbserver

I already know there is a vulnerability in the a.cgi file. Because I analyzed a.cgi file.

a.cgi file used from lighttpd process.

So, I want attach **ida pro** with **gdbserver.**

I'm already try this...

lighttpd process id is - `12345`

> ./gdbserver IP:port --attach 12345

--> IT's **FAIL**

> ./gdbserver IP:port a.cgi

--> IT's **FAIL**

Can i debugging a.cgi with gdbserver??

Comment: If you are not running lighttpd as root, then you should have no problem attaching a debugger and setting follow-fork mode to child. If you are running as root, then I recommend setting up a test environment which uses an unprivileged port and is not started as root.

Comment: @gstrauss lighttpd is running as root mips little endian architecture. And I have root privileges. **Can i use follow-fork with gdbserver and IDA Pro?**  As i know, follow-fork mode is available in gdb only. Isn't it?